# How do I use add the image field Product entity in to my view?

Tags: views, commerce, entities

I'm using Drupal 7.28, Views 7.x-3.8 and Commerce 7.x-1.9.

I've created lots of products in the Products section and I've also created some product displays. For example, I have created a round oak table, square oak table and a rectangle oak table. I have then created a product display called Old Oak Table and I've referenced the three oak tables.

Now I need to create a view that lists all tables. My view needs to show one image from each product display.

I was unable to add the image field to my view - so I added a Product reference and I'm now able to add the Image field which is on the Product entity not the content type.

Now that I've added the image field, my view shows every product image so for example the round table, the square table and the rectangle table - I just need it to show one image from each product display, so for example just one image from the Old Oak Table product display.

Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show just a single image, you can add a filter to the view to restrict the product reference field to delta 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do I do this? I've gone into my view then add filter criteria and then what should I do? Should I add Content: Product Reference (field_product_reference:delta) is that what you mean? When I add that field though I have chose choose an operator which I'm not sure what to choose

Comment: Yes, that's the one, add that as a filter and choose delta equals 0